# Notation of inf

Tags: notation

In [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0362546X83900494#) (equation 4.1) the following formula is listed:

$\inf_{u \in R} \left \{ \frac{\partial V}{\partial \boldsymbol{x}}f(\boldsymbol{x},u)  \right \} < 0, \quad \forall \boldsymbol{x} \neq \boldsymbol{0} $

Now I don't understand what the term $\inf_{u \in R}$ indicates. I know that inf stands for infimum, but I can not make any sense out of this notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $$\inf_{u \in \Bbb R} \left \{ \frac{\partial V}{\partial {\bf x}}f({\bf x},u)  \right \} < 0, \quad \forall \ {\bf x}\neq {\bf 0}$$

is the same as: $$\inf \left \{ \frac{\partial V}{\partial {\bf x}}f({\bf x},u)\mid u \in \Bbb R  \right \} < 0, \quad \forall \ {\bf x}\neq {\bf 0}$$

That is, the infimum is being taken on $u$.

Answer (score 2):

The subscript gives context to the infimum.  You could also write it as
$$
\inf\left\{\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} f(x,u)\ \bigg| \ u \in R\right\}
$$